# Efficiency of a gravity feed hose

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, water

If I am trying to fill a large cylindrical container with a gravity feed hose, would it be more efficient, time-wise, to drill a hole in the bottom of the container for a greater initial pressure until the backflow of the water decreases the pressure, or drill a hole in the top of the container for a lower initial pressure but successfully avoiding backflow? The reservoir would be presumably placed high enough to provide strong enough pressure to fill the container either way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the hose length is the same, and ignoring any restrictions caused by bends in the hose, you want as great a gravity and pressure difference as possible to pull the liquid through. If you have the hose end at the top of the destination container, with the liquid falling down to the level of the already-moved liquid, then you aren't getting as much pressure difference as possible, and so the flow will be reduced relative to having the hose at the bottom of the destination container.

The ideal situation would be to have the end of the hose always at the surface of the already-moved liquid, giving you maximum suction. However, there is no penalty for having the hose end deeper in the liquid, as the liquid pressure outside the end of the hose will be exactly matched by the pressure of the additional column of liquid inside the hose.

Comment: "However, there is no penalty for having the hose end deeper in the liquid, as the liquid pressure outside the end of the hose will be exactly matched by the pressure of the additional column of liquid inside the hose."

I'm sorry, could you explain this more in detail? Wouldn't the liquid pressure outside the hose build up as the liquid accumulates?

Comment: Yes it would, and that would slow down the liquid transfer. However, if you instead kept the hose at the (rising) surface of the liquid, then the gravity force on the liquid in the hose would identically decrease, again slowing down the liquid flow.

Comment: Think of a vertical, open pipe submerged in water. The pressure is higher at the bottom, so why doesn't water spontaneously start rising through the tube? Of course, it's because the pressure change outside is exactly matched by the pressure change inside. The same principle would apply to your hose.

Comment: Hmm...Okay. So would the slowing down of the liquid due to decrease in the gravity force on the liquid in the "rising" hose be numerically equivalent to the slowing down of the liquid flow when the hose is simply left stationary at the bottom of the cylinder?
Edited for clarification

Comment: Yes. (11 more characters needed.)